# como accedo a esta propiedad en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

necesito acceder al "40", es en laravel, realmente lo que necesito es sumar los valores de una columna pero dependiendo de su id de referncia

> object(stdClass)#263 (1) { ["sum(cantidad_entrada)"]=> string(2) "40" }

```
public function index()
{

    $inventario = DB::table('inventarios')
    ->join('productos', 'inventarios.fk_producto', '=', 'productos.id_producto')
    ->join('entradas', 'inventarios.fk_entrada', '=', 'entradas.id_entrada')
    ->join('salidas', 'inventarios.fk_salida', '=', 'salidas.id_salida')
    ->select('productos.descripcion', 'inventarios.*', 'salidas.cantidad_salida','entradas.cantidad_entrada')
    ->get();

    $entradas = DB::table('entradas')
    ->join('productos', 'entradas.fk_producto_entrada', '=', 'productos.id_producto')
    ->select('entradas.cantidad_entrada')
    ->get();

    $salidas = DB::select('select sum(cantidad_salida) as cantidad_salida from salidas');

    return view('inventario.index', compact('inventario', 'entradas', 'salidas'));
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega tu código como texto

Comment: Hola, deberías poder acceder utilizando un alias. 

`$entradas = DB::select("select sum(cantidad_entrada) as cantidad_entrada from entradas");`

Despues solamente tendrias que acceder a la propiedad como un objeto cualquiera:
 `$entradas->cantidad_entrada`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el metodo sum de query builder de esta forma

```
$entradas = DB::table('entradas')->sum('cantidad_entrada');
```

Comment: como pongo un where

Comment: De la misma forma para un query builder normal `DB::table('entradas')->where('columna', 'elemento')->sum('cantidad_entrada')`

Answer (score 1):

Procura incluir el uso de los modelos siempre que te sea posible, lo que eventualmente le dará mas calidad y orden a tu código.

Perfectamente lo que muestras puede quedar de esta forma:

Usa el modelo `Salida` y accede al método estático `sum` el cual recibe como argumento en forma de *string* el nombre de la columna.

```
$salidas = Salida::sum('cantidad_salida');
```

Posterior como leo en uno de los comentarios para incluir un `where` puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```
$salidas = Salida::where('columna1' 'valor1')->sum('cantidad_salida');
```

Finalmente cuando quisieras acceder al valor devuelto por dicha consulta en tu vista solo harías lo siguiente:

```
{{ $salidas }}
```